# How can I use the ampersand and a delimiter in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to read the following dat file into SAS. Since the names and values are separated by 2 spaces I use the ampersand in the input statement. But it seems that the `DLM='/'` in the infile statement conflicts with it. Can someone tell me what the mistake in my code is?

File:

```
1118 ART CONTUCK  57.69/65.20/120.50//152.60
2287 MICHAEL WINSTONE  145.89
```

Code:

```
data mylib.D_report;
infile Dinning dlm='/' dsd missover;
input ID 1-4 Name & $17. M1-M6;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing input styles, which while understandable given you have fairly mixed input data, isn't permitted the way you're doing it.

Your best option is to read M1-6 into one variable, then split it up using SCAN.

```
data work.D_report;
infile datalines missover dlm=' ';
input ID :4.
      Name & $17. 
      Ms :$40.;

array M[6];
do _t = 1 to countc(Ms,'/')+1;
 if _t > dim(M) then leave;
 M[_t]=scan(Ms,_t,'/','m');
end;
datalines;
1118 ART CONTUCK  57.69/65.20/120.50//152.60
2287 MICHAEL WINSTONE  145.89
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use arrays this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the delimiter.

```
data D_report;
   dlm = ' ';
   infile cards dlm=dlm missover dsd;
   input ID 1-4 Name & $17. @;
   dlm = '/';
   input M1-M6;
   cards;
1118 ART CONTUCK  57.69/65.20/120.50//152.60
2287 MICHAEL WINSTONE  145.89
run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]